# Initialize static variable objects to the same value

Tags: c++, static, initialization

I want to initialize all static variable objects to the same value. I have a class defined in `prog1.h`

```
  namespace fal {
    class read_f{
    public:
        static std::string ref_content, seq_content;
        int read_fasta(int argc, char **argv);
    };
}
```

And I tried to initialize them in `prog1.cpp`

```
std::string fal::read_f::ref_content = seq_content = "";
```

But I get `undefined reference error`.

When I try

```
std::string fal::read_f::ref_content = "" ;
std::string fal::read_f::seq_content = "";
```

it works fine.

How can I initialize in one line?

Comment: well you also cannot do int a = b = 10 when you havent declared b

Comment: @JoshKisb Is not `a` and `b` defined in the class.

Comment: @AaghazHussain `std::string fal::read_f::ref_content = seq_content = "";` does not define `seq_content` (which is the source of your problem). Your class only contains declarations.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Do you mean `std::string fal::read_f::ref_content , seq_content ; ref_content = seq_content = "";` should work.

Comment: they are not declared in the class. thats why if you try to assign them a value without initializing in global you will get errors because they do not exist

Comment: `std::string fal::read_f::ref_content = "", fal::read_f::seq_content = "";`

Comment: @Yola Is it possible without repeating `fal::read_f::` every time when I have tens of variables.

Comment: Have you tried std::string fal::read_f::ref_content,seq_content = "" ; ?

Comment: Can you use C++17? If so, you can make them `inline`.

Comment: If you are outside your class no, you have to specify the scope of the variable before you use it. You could have a seq_content outside your class, how does the compiler knows which one you refer to then?

Comment: I think no, but you can use `using`.

Comment: @JoshKisb Please, at the very least, read the question before commenting. 1) They are declared in the class. 2) The error is not about fields not existing, but rather about them not being defined.

Comment: jeez i am trying to explain that exact issue but you are not listening. static class variables have to be initialized outside of the class otherwise they dont exist

Comment: @AaghazHussain The thing is.. `ref_content = seq_content = "";` is an assignment, not an initialization, in the context you written it in, hence it can't be written in a global scope.

Comment: The section $9.4.2/7 from the C++ Standard says,

Static data members are initialized and destroyed exactly like non-local objects (3.6.2, 3.6.3).

Comment: @JoshKisb You are seem to be confusing terminology. 1) You stated "_they are not declared in the class_", yet it's plainly wrong: they are. 2) The terminology of "_you will get errors because they do not exist_" is ambiguous, since it is closer to the meaning `use of undeclared identifier`. Yet, the compiler will compile such code just fine. It's only the linker fails, due to lacking definitions (the term, you didn't even mention).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius ooooh you must be right. my English must be bonkers. but glad you understand what i mean my lad. when it doesnt exist then no need for errors. plus its initialization not assignment

Comment: @JoshKisb Once again you are commenting upon things you didn't read. 1) I didn't mention term "assignment" in my comment to you, hence I must infer that you are referring to my comment to OP. 2) Did you read the comment I was replying to? I was referring to a snippet from the following example: `std::string fal::read_f::ref_content , seq_content ; ref_content = seq_content = "";` Since `ref_content = seq_content = "";` Is a separate statement - it's no longer an initialization, and, in this context, it's assignment.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I am using `c++17`

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius and what does that have to do with anything. are you just replying to me to get my attention. am a busy man my lad

Comment: @JoshKisb 1) You "corrected" me with, obviously, wrong statement. Since I don't like you spreading misinformation, which is related to me, I pointed out, why your statement is wrong. From my perspective: it is your intention at grabbing attention, due to purposefully providing wrong information. 2) If you were truly busy - you wouldn't have bothered writing such a comment.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius i dont know what made you think i was correcting you. i was clearly agreeing with you

Answer (score 3):

You inline them with a comma. If you do not want to repeat the `fal::` qualifier, you can use a `using` declaration:

```
using fal::read_f;
std::string read_f::ref_content = "", read_f::seq_content = "";
```

Additionally, since C++17 you can make those two variables `inline`, so that they *may be defined in the class definition* ([class.static.data]).

Comment: Is this the best bet we can have

Comment: @AaghazHussain I think that is the best, apart from you can define variable for `""` you can't do anything, because on the left of `=` operator you need to have `lvalue`, but without prior definitions these names doesn't evaluate to objects, bit-field or functions, so their are not glvalues and hence not lvalues.